# SFINAE doesn't work in recursive function

Tags: c++, templates, recursion, sfinae, overload-resolution

Let's create [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) function.

```
template <typename TFunc, typename TArg>
class CurryT
{
public:
    CurryT(const TFunc &func, const TArg &arg)
      : func(func), arg(arg )
        {}

    template <typename... TArgs>
        decltype(auto) operator()(TArgs ...args) const
            { return func(arg, args...); }

private:
    TFunc func;
    TArg  arg ;
};

template <typename TFunc, typename TArg>
    CurryT<decay_t<TFunc>, remove_cv_t<TArg>>
        Curry(const TFunc &func, const TArg &arg)
            { return {func, arg}; }
```

And function that decouple function to single argument functions:

```
// If single argument function (F(int)).
template <typename F>
    static auto Decouple(const F &f, enable_if_t<is_invocable_v<F, int>> * = nullptr)
    {
        return f;
    }

// If multiple arguments function (F(int, int, ...)).
template <typename F>
    static auto Decouple(const F &f, enable_if_t<!is_invocable_v<F, int>> * = nullptr)
    {
        return [f](int v) { return Decouple( Curry(f, v) ); };
    }
```

Everything works fine if 2 arguments function is passed:

```
auto f1 = Decouple(
    [](int a, int b)
        { std::cout << a << " " << b << std::endl; }
);
f1(3)(4); // Outputs 3 4
```

But if I add more arguments

```
auto f2 = Decouple(
    [](int a, int b, int c)
        { std::cout << a << " " << b << " " << c << std::endl; }
);
f(5)(6)(7);
```

The compilation breaks: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/10c6dba670d17ffa

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'decltype(auto) CurryT<TFunc, TArg>::operator()(TArgs ...) const [with TArgs = {int}; TFunc = main()::<lambda(int, int, int)>; TArg = int]':

main.cpp:17:26: error: no match for call to '(const main()::<lambda(int, int, int)>) (const int&, int&)'
   17 |             { return func(arg, args...); }
```

It breaks in instantiation of `std::is_invocable`.

Since debugging the standard library is hard, I created simple versions of standard type traits classes:

```
template <typename F> true_type  check(const F &, decltype( declval<F>()(1) )* );
template <typename F> false_type check(const F &, ...);

template <typename F>
    struct invocable_with_int : decltype(check(declval<F>(), nullptr))
        {};

template <typename F>
    inline constexpr bool invocable_with_int_v = invocable_with_int<F>::value;

template<bool B>
    struct my_enable_if {};

template<>
    struct my_enable_if<true>
        { using type = void; };

template <bool B>
    using my_enable_if_t = typename my_enable_if<B>::type;
```

The problem remains the same https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/722a2041600799b0:

```
main.cpp:29:73:   required by substitution of 'template<class F> std::true_type check(const F&, decltype (declval<F>()(1))*) [with F = CurryT<main()::<lambda(int, int, int)>, int>]'
```

It tries to resolve calling to this function:

```
template <typename F> true_type  check(const F &, decltype( declval<F>()(1) )* );
```

But `decltype (declval<F>()(1))*)` fails. But shouldn't this function be removed from overload resolution because template substitution fails? It works when `Decouple` is called first time. But when it is called second time the SFINAE seems to be disabled, and the first failure of template substitution gives a compilation error. Are there some limitation on secondary SFINAE? Why calling template function recursively doesn't work?

The problem is reproduced in GCC and Clang. So it is not a compiler bug.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `operator()` overload is completely unconstrained and therefore claims to be callable with any set of arguments. Only declarations, not definitions, are inspected to determine which function to call in overload resolution. If substitution into the definition then fails, SFINAE does not apply.

So, constrain your `operator()` to require `TFunc` to be callable with `TArg` and `TArgs...` as arguments.

For example:

```
template <typename... TArgs>
auto operator()(TArgs ...args) const -> decltype(func(arg, args...))
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you. I spent so much time trying to resolve that issue. But what I still don't understand why my non-working solution works when passing the function with 2 arguments. I should fail on the first call to Decouple, but it doesn't.

Comment: @anton_rh With two arguments, you only try to test `std::is_invocable<F, int>` with `F` a `CurryT` where it really does expect one `int` argument. There is only an issue when you have a `CurryT` instance that expects to be called with two or more arguments, in which case `std::is_invocable<F, int>` still gives `true` because of the lack of constraints.

Comment: Oh, understand. At the first call (when there are 2 arguments) it is not `CurryT`, it is lambda. And `std::is_invocable_v` works fine with lambdas. At the second call it is `CarryT`. But then it works because in that specific case `CarryT` works with single `int` argument. Thank you.

Comment: PS I added `const` to `CurryT` for not allowing to change `arg` when calling `func` (if it accepts the first argument by reference and modifies it). In other case it would not be classic currying. I also ommited `&&` and `std::forward` to make example simple.

Comment: I resolved the issue by simply using trailing return type with `decltype`. In this case trying to call function with single argument becomes part of declaration. https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/46c680dfc72a1b72

Comment: @anton_rh Yes, that is a better approach and avoids having to consider the type qualifiers. For some reason it doesn't seem to work with your custom type-traits version, but I'll just assume that this is just a bug in your custom trait implementations.

Comment: It [works](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/263e16069148bc1d). The only issue was that I used wrong variable name (`f` instead of `f2`).

Comment: @anton_rh Ah yes, and I forgot to adjust the declaration order in the class.

Answer (score 0):

For me it is strange that your `CurryT::operator()` accepts unknown number of arguments.

Since aim is to have a functions which accept only one argument I expected that this function will accept only one argument.

IMO depending what kind of function `CurryT` holds `CurryT::operator()` should return a different type: return type of starting function or another version of `CurryT`.

Here is my approach using `std::bind_front` from C++20:

```cpp
namespace detail {
template <typename TFunc>
class CurryT
{
public:
    explicit CurryT(TFunc f) : mF(std::move(f))
    {}

    template<typename T>
    auto get(T&& x, int = 0) -> decltype(std::declval<TFunc>()(x)) {
        return mF(x);
    }

    template<typename T>
    auto get(T&& x, char) {
        return CurryT<decltype(std::bind_front(mF, std::forward<T>(x)))>{
            std::bind_front(mF, std::forward<T>(x))
        };
    }

    template<typename T>
    auto operator()(T&& x)
    {
        return this->get(std::forward<T>(x), 1);
    }
private:
     TFunc mF;
};
}

template<typename F>
auto Decouple(F&& f)
{
    return detail::CurryT<std::decay_t<F>>{std::forward<F>(f)};
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/eW9r4Y6Ea

Note with this approach integer argument is not forced like in your solution.